# How to redirect to another page at a breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have to redirect to another webpage at a breakpoint of 800px

I have tried the below code and tried in incorporate at a breakpoint, but it was always redirecting even at the above breakpoints

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
          content="2;  
                url=http://redirectedSite.com/">
```

needed to make the page to be redirected to another page at a breakpoint using HTMl or JS

Comment: You want to redirect when the page is loaded or when the browser is resized?

Comment: browser is resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with plain javascript. Add an Event Listener for browser resize and check for browser window width and redirect.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', screen_resize);
 
function screen_resize() {
  var h = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
  var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

  if(w <= 800) {
      window.location.replace("http://redirectedSite.com/");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think this javascript code should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (screen.width > 800) {
      window.location.replace("http://redirectedSite.com");
   }
</script>
```

Please note that this redirecting is bad practice.

If this is for getting a different screen layout you should just change your layout using css.

You could use `@media (min-width: 800px) { your css }` to only effect users using larger devices.

Comment: thanks man, and about the redirect I have a desktop version as well as mobile version sites but Cloudflare wasnt doing a good job to redirecting to "m.myWebsite.com". In case if the user ends up in desktop version through mobile it will redirect to mobile version.